# kubernetes: Demystify warning about failed readiness probe

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I am seeing this in my `kubectl get events --watch` output

```
46m         Warning   Unhealthy                Pod                       Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.1.43.253:15020/healthz/ready: dial tcp 10.1.43.253:15020: connect: connection refused
```

The log does not mention what pod is failing to provide its readines probe. (although as it becomes apparent, this comes from `istio`)

Using GKE with version `v1.12.7-gke.25` on both masters and nodes, on top of `istio`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the pod with the IP 10.1.43.253.